# What are the cheats in simcity?

Tags: simcity-2013

When enabling sandbox mode in Simcity it says it enables cheats. What are these cheats and how do you use them?

Comment: Try this:
http://www.ign.com/wikis/simcity/Cheats_and_Secrets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to enable cheats in SimCity, you will first of all need to create a region in Sandbox mode - once you're in the city, you can enable individual cheats by using any of the following key combinations;

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - Add §100000 to your City Budget

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> - Toggle Air Pollution On/Off

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> - Toggle Crime On/Off

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> - Toggle Fire On/Off

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> - Toggle Ground Pollution On/Off

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> - Toggle Health Issues On/Off

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> - Toggle Homeless Sims On/Off

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - Toggle Sewage On/Off

Comment: Did you try it out recently btw? Because I tried last week on the first day after launch and the money cheat was not working. I figured it must be a bug but didn't try afterwards..

Comment: yes - I have tested each of the above and they work as described.